# Change the main menu Alignment in Avada Theme Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want change the main menu of Avada Wordpress Theme in the header to be left-aligned not right,

it is like this:
[image]

and I want it to be like this:
[image]

How can I do that in the CSS?

Notes:

I did that using the CSS, but the problem that it is not working in all screen sizes when I tested it, I did that with this code:

```
 .fusion-main-menu {
    position:static; 
    text-align:left;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 30%; 
    margin-top:4px; 
}
```

but it is not made it fixed aligned to the left with the same space in all screen sizes :(

Answer (score 0):

Avada has option of create "Layout Builder".
With this option, you can create global header with avada page editor as per your need. And keep button out side of navigation to maintain left right position.
[image]

**Using CSS Only :**
Use `.fusion-main-menu { float: left; padding-left: 50px; }` and use JS to get last button to out of nav tag. and apply float:right to that buttton.

`jQuery( ".fusion-main-menu li:last-child" ).wrap("<div class='cst_btn'></div>"); jQuery(".cst_btn").insertAfter(".fusion-main-menu");` Make sure you have menu with ".fusion-main-menu" class only once on page else use diff class or ID.

Comment: I did that but this is not works with the mega menu used in the services section, this is made the mega menu hided, also I am using a Max Mega menu plug-in and if I used the custom header it will enable it, so I want to do that by using the CSS

Comment: Also, I did that using the CSS, but the problem that it is not working in all screen sizes when I tested it, I did that: 

.fusion-main-menu {
    position:static;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 30%;
    margin-top:4px;
}

but it is not made it fixed aligned to the left with the same space in all screen sizes :( how I can fix it?

Comment: Use 
.fusion-main-menu {
 float: left;
 padding-left: 50px;
}
and use JS to get last button to out of nav tag. and apply float:right to that buttton.
Need JS for that?

Comment: Thank you! it works for the CSS, and please if you can help me with the JS, I don't know how to do it

Comment: jQuery( ".fusion-main-menu li:last-child" ).wrap("<div class='cst_btn'></div>");
jQuery(".cst_btn").insertAfter(".fusion-main-menu");

Make sure you have menu with ".fusion-main-menu" class only once on page else use diff class or ID.

Comment: I added it and it didn't work , I have only one CSS class with the name ".fusion-main-menu" but I have something like that in the page: ".fusion-main-menu .sub-menu li a" , is that effect?